# A tough sudoku puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Here is a tough sudoku puzzle from my blog

[image]

Comment: Hello! Your question has likely been downvoted not because of its quality but because you keep adding a link to your blog as if you're advertising it. Its fine to say you've created the puzzle and to link to your blog in your profile, but continuing to add a link to your blog in your questions will likely lead to more downvotes.

Comment: I fully understand. You are right, I am advertising it. I put a lot of time into researching the programming required to create my puzzles and even longer writing the actual programs. If you cannot accept a link beside a puzzle I give you I will just have to find other places to share my content. I apologise for any inconvenience I may have caused.

Comment: Some people don't like similar topics being posted frequently.

Comment: It's certainly harder than the typically "Will Shortz" type of Sudokus. If you want to rate the difficulty, you can pop into a solver like this: https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm and see what techniques are required . This one needs Y-wings and Simple Coloring in addition to the "standard" methods

Comment: All sudoku puzzles on my blog (including this one) have a link to work on them online. They also have a link to render them automatically in Andrew Stuart's solver (sudokuwiki.org as mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

**Final Solution for the sudoku is:**

> [image: Solved Sudoku]